# What does SH stands for in file permission

Tags: unix, ftp, file-permissions

I am parsing some directory lines using FTP and I am getting an error on this type of file:

```
drwx----SH   1   user   group   2048   JUL 27 2012   FOUND.000
```

Does anyone know what SH mean ?

Thanks.

Comment: It can mean anything because FTP listing formats are not standardized.

Comment: what server host are you on, and what shell produced the output you posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the name (it looks like one of those files created as part of disk repair), it's probably a Windows server at the other end, in which case `SH` would probably be a hidden system file.

Windows files attributes have (at a minimum) hidden, system and read-only.

Comment: Yeah, it is a hidden file, so your probably right.